# examples of user feedback for evaluation of other users' answers

Tags: website-design, web-app, feedback, web, expert-review

As an academic project, I'm developing a simple facebook application. I intend it to be some kind of a mind game exploring creativity.

Its current design is simple: the user just writes a short phrase as creative as he/she can think of as an answer to a given question, then the question and the answer are evaluated by other users.

My problem is the evaluation interface. After some testing we realized people were confusing creativity with originality, so we decided to be more specific and show 2 tick selectors below the proposed question and answer to evaluate:

1. This answer is intelligible (I understand it, it's related enough
   to the question and in my opinion it makes enough sense to accept it
   as a valid answer)
2. This answer is original (An answer like this wouldn't be in the top of my mind if I were asked the same thing)

I have a clear idea of what I want but I have no clue on how should it look like from the interface point of view.

Can you give me some related examples you have encountered or implemented and liked that can help me decide which way to go?

Some ideas I thought of:

Should it be a button, a text link, an image changing on hover? which kind of image/s?

Should I have a third link/button/ticker to mark it as creative, which would automatically select the other two?

Should I also have a like button to mark when an answer is particularly interesting to the evaluator or is it already implied as it is?

(Of course the effectiveness of this method is in question, because the creative effort is almost as much on the person who thinks of the answer as on the persons evaluating that answer, but since there are many evaluators we are hoping to be able to determine with some certainty which users and answers are more creative, so we decided to leave that discussion behind and test it anyway.)

Comment: There is a lot going on in this question, it's quite broad and there isn't a correct answer to this. Can you rephrase it so that it's a single, answerable question? Asking for examples isn't really a constructive question, but if you say *"I want to do 'x', I have tried doing 'y' but that's not working so is there a better way to achieve 'x'"* then that's a more answerable question than just requesting lists of examples.

Comment: you're right, but at this moment I can't make this question more specific: I did leave out some other aspects I'm in doubt of for future questions though it's all related, but it's not enough because this is more of a discussion forum topic. Do you know of any appropiate forum where I can register and repost it?

Answer (score 1):

You can have an answer which is both creative and original or creative and intelligible or other permutations of the above. I would recommend a simple approach where people can just mark the answer as either of the three or  a combination of the three depending upon they feel and the corresponding counters are updated per answer to give a total score.

I would say yelp does this really well as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

With regards to your question,

> Should I also have a like button to mark when an answer is
>   particularly interesting to the evaluator or is it already implied as
>   it is?

I am not really sure what you mean here, are you asking for a way for the user to favorite a question. Then I would recommend using something like a favorite icon or you could take a leaf out of Yelp's book and bookmark it or even do it as stack exchange does

[image]

Comment: star as favorite instead of like, yes, that would be appropiate. Thanks!

Comment: regarding originality: Are you sure a proper answer (understandable and properly related to the question, so lets say valid instead of intelligible like I mention in my post) can be original without being creative? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Well the concept of creative is a pretty difficult thing to define and varies from person to person, so what might seem like a creative answer to one might not seem to another. For example, this urban legend http://www.thespacereview.com/article/613/1 ,if true would have been considered as a very original solution by me but not a creative one

Comment: You can think of it as a creative answer because it broadens the search category to find a writing instrument instead of a pen, that's the outside the box or divergent thinking definition of creativity we have in mind, but for many people it can be too obvious to consider it relevant enough and that's why the story leaves NASA researchers as quite the square minded, and not necessarily the russians as geniouses, but it's all a matter of perspective and that's just mine, so it would be interesting to know many others and treat it statistically...

Comment: well its a view and as I said,it depends on the person's mindset,so what might seem as creative to you might not seem as creative to me

Comment: So I would check original and intelligible and you would check original and intelligible but you think it's not creative and I do. That's interesting...

Comment: The way people percieve things are different,you cant assume everyone thinks the same way